# Does change of DBML file clears user session as web.config?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, linq-to-sql

Does change of DBML file clears user session as web.config does?

What could be a consequence of changing dbml file on live?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is **NO**.

The problem with restarting application occurs when I make changes in App_Code. In my case dbml file is in that folder. What is interesting sometime when I make changes it restart, sometime it not restart. For example modifying some file is fine but deleting empty folder triggers restart.

Remember to not loose all user sessions you can use state server.

Answer (score 0):

There is no relationship between the context and session dbml defined by the configuration of the application

Answer (score 0):

I don't think changing the DBML file in production will do anything.

The code that is generated from the DBML file is what is actually used in your C# code...not the DMBL file itself.

Visual Studio creates the classes that are used in your code after you save a DBML file.